# Анимация градиента

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Первый раз с таким столкнулась. Мне нужна анимация градиента, что бы была еле заметной. Получилось найти такой вариант(https://wp-lessons.com/tsvetovaya-animatsiya-teksta-css), но анимация дикая какая-то. Вот код. Помогите сделать анимацию незаметной.

```css
body{
height: 683px;
 max-height: 100%; 
 background: 
 linear-gradient(to top left, #c04481, transparent 54%),
 linear-gradient(to right, rgba(163,65,147,1) 0%, rgba(192,65,126,1) 19%, rgba(220,83,94,1) 51%, rgba(222,89,89,1) 62%, rgba(228,119,72,1) 83%, rgba(234,160,49,1) 100%);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
 -webkit-animation: animate-logo;
 -webkit-animation-delay: 0;
 -webkit-animation-duration: 7s;
 -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
 -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
 -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
 transition: font-size 500ms ease-in-out;
}
@-webkit-keyframes animate-logo {
 20% {
 background-position: 0 1200px;
 }
 100% {
 background-position: 1200px 0;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Анимировать полноэкранные градиенты крайне не рекомендуется, но надо, так надо...

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(to top, transparent, #c04481, transparent), linear-gradient(to right, rgba(163, 65, 147), rgba(163, 65, 147), rgb(204, 75, 85), rgb(208, 103, 57), rgba(234, 160, 49), rgba(234, 160, 49), rgb(208, 103, 57), rgb(204, 75, 85), rgba(163, 65, 147));
  background-size: 200% 200%;
  animation: 40s infinite linear animate-v, 30s infinite ease animate-h;
}

@-webkit-keyframes animate-h {
  from { background-position-x: 0%; }
  to { background-position-x: 200%; }
}

@-webkit-keyframes animate-v {
  from { background-position-y: -200%; }
  to { background-position-y: 200%; }
}
```